# Android Compatibility Build Problems

Tags: android, android-compatibility

**BACKGROUND**

I am developing an android application that needs to work on API levels from 7 to 16.

**THE PROBLEM**

Whenever I go to build my project this is the process I have to go through.

1. Clean project
2. Run Project
3. "Errors in project" > Click OK > Run Project Again
4. Runs fine on any API

I think the problem is due to the fact I am including code (such as the ActionBar) that API < 3.0 can't use but I am checking for it and running something else if thats the case.

**THE QUESTION**

Does anyone know a way round this because it is very time consuming considering I have to do this every time I want to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using Eclipse for your development. You can annotate the offending methods as follows:

```
private final int VERSION = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
private File myDir;
// some stuff here
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void doSomething() {
    if (VERSION < 8) {
        // Uses a method available since API 1
        myDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
     else {
        // Uses a method available since API 8
        myDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    }
    // Do more stuff
}
```

Comment: You have just saved me the accumulated time of 300 hours :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Then any API between and including 7 and 16 versions will compile because your target is 16.

Then if your device is 7 any API > 7 will fail on your device but you have said you are taking measures against that in your code.